# passing argument in function - OpenCV & Cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, argument-passing

I've been back & forth with this problem for a while especially since I started to OpenCV library. The fact is, in OpenCV, there are several methods used:

- 1st: funcA((const) CvMat arg)
- 2nd: funcA((const) CvMat& arg)
- 3rd: funcA((const) CvMat* arg)
- 4th: funcA((const) CvMat*& arg) => I've just seen and currently been stuck at this

and of course, corresponding to each method, the caller format and the function implementation should be different.

What is the significance about all of these derivatives?? especially the last one (I've not yet understood its usage)

Comment: The fourth one allows you to alter the argument within the function, i.e. caller calls funcA (ptr) with ptr pointing to something, within the function you write arg = p; , and after returning from the function ptr points to the target of p.

Comment: how about the '&'?? is it there only to free the mind of function user? i.e. caller: funcA(pointer) (it's not caller: funcA(&pointer))

Comment: then, what is it the difference with funcA(CvMat* arg), within funcA, I think I still can assign arg = some_other_pointer ??

Comment: The caller syntax does not have too be different for the first two or the last two. But the semantics are quite different. Look up pass by value and pass by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the `(const)` for now, and using `int` for clarity:

Pass by value makes a copy in the body of the function

```
void funcA(int arg) {
  // arg here is a copy
  // anything I do to arg has no effect on caller side.
  arg++; // only has effect locally
}
```

Note that it semantically makes a copy, but the compiler is allowed to elide the copies under certain conditions. Look up [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Pass by reference. I can modify the argument passed by the caller.

```
void funcA(int& arg) {
  // arg here is a reference
  // anything I do to arg is seen on caller side.
  arg++;
}
```

Pass pointer *by value*. I get a copy of the pointer, but it points to the same object pointed at by the caller's argument

```
void funcA(int* arg) {
  // changes to arg do not affect caller's argument
  // BUT I can change the object pointed to
  (*arg)++; // pointer unchanged, pointee changed. Caller sees it.
}
```

Pass reference to pointer. I can change the pointed itself and the caller will see the change.

```
void funcA(int*& arg) {
  // changes to arg affect caller's argument
  // AND I can change the object pointed to.
  (*arg)++; // pointee changed
  arg++; // pointer changed. Caller sees it.
}
```

As you can see, the second two are just the same as the first two, except that they deal with pointers. If you understand what pointers do, then there is no difference conceptually.

Concerning `const`, it specifies whether the argument can be modified or not, or, if the arguments are references or pointers, whether what they point to/refer to can be modified. The positioning of `const` is important here. See [const correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness) for example.

Comment: in your 3rd example, after funcA is executed, *arg pointee is changed but arg pointer remains unchanged in caller's scope. Is that right? even if I added arg++ in funcA?

Comment: as waht you mean, I think, your commments in the last example is not precise. "changes to arg do not affect caller's argument" should be "changes to arg affects caller's argument". Moreover, I can change both pointee & pointer inside funcA such as: (*arg)++; arg++; Am I understanding it right??

Comment: @SonLe you are right, that was a typo in the last example. You are understanding right!